# BeautifulSoup: How to extract <li> information within a <div>

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-lists

I am trying to extract `li` information within a `div` using BeautifulSoup.

Here is sample code of the `div` I am working with:

```
<div class="list">
<a href="/name1" target="_blank" title="name1">
<img alt="name1" src="https://img.url.com/name1"/>
<ul>
<li>name1</li>
<li>fullname1</li>
</ul>
</a>
<a href="/name2" target="_blank" title="name2">
<img alt="name2" src="https://img.url.com/name2"/>
<ul>
<li>name2</li>
<li>fullname2</li>
</ul>
</a>
<a href="/name3" target="_blank" title="name3">
<img alt="name3" src="https://img.url.com/name3"/>
<ul>
<li>name3</li>
<li>fullname3</li>
</ul>
</a>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is extract both the 'name' and 'fullname' text from the two `li`.

I think I need to create a `for` loop to iterate through the lists, but I am not sure how to do this. (In actuality, the list is longer than just three entries).

The other problem I am running into is how to get soup to differentiate between first `<li>name<li>` and second `<li>fullname<li>` tags.

Your help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested comprehensions with `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
_div = soup(content, 'html.parser').find('div', {'class':'list'})
results = [[i.text for i in b.find_all('li')] for b in _div.find_all('ul')]
```

Output:

```
[['name1', 'fullname1'], ['name2', 'fullname2'], ['name3', 'fullname3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your lists within this div will always follow the above format you can search by selectors. This will produce a list of alternating `names` and `fullnames`.

```py
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

In [2]: soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')

In [3]: target = soup.select('div ul li')
# search by selector

In [4]: target
Out[4]:
[<li>name1</li>,
 <li>fullname1</li>,
 <li>name2</li>,
 <li>fullname2</li>,
 <li>name3</li>,
 <li>fullname3</li>]

In [5]: names = [n.text for n in target[::2]]
# select every second element starting at the beginning of the list

In [6]: names
Out[6]: [u'name1', u'name2', u'name3']

In [7]: fullnames = [f.text for f in target[1::2]]
# select every second element starting at the second element of the list

In [8]: fullnames
Out[8]: [u'fullname1', u'fullname2', u'fullname3']
```